# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 20 how to solve

Tags: php, arrays

how to solve this issue the raw array is

```
Array ( [1] => 50 [ 2] => 100 [ 3] => 150 [ 4] => 175 [ 5] => 200 [ 6] => 225 [ 7] => 250 )
```

Code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("bin\PriceDays.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $string = fread($myfile,filesize("bin\PriceDays.txt"));
    //string to array
    $a = explode(',', $string);

    foreach ($a as $result) {
        $b = explode('. ', $result);
        $PriceDays[$b[0]] = $b[1];
    }

    print_r($PriceDays);
    echo $PriceDays[2];




    fclose($myfile);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a space after `,` in your input, so `$b[0]` will begin with a space. Use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace.

```
foreach ($a as $result) {
    $b = explode('. ', $result);
    $PriceDays[trim($b[0])] = trim($b[1]);
}
```